# Свое поле в умном фильтре, в Битрикс управление сайтом

Tags: javascript, php, html, битрикс

Всех приветствую! Есть свойство типа "Число". В умном фильтре можно вывести фильтрацию "От" и "До". Но мне нужно, чтобы не руками вписывали от скольки до скольки, а выбирали из выпадающего списка "От 100 до 200", "От 200 до 300" и тд. Как правильно поступить в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы попробовал такой вариант: добавить обработчик, который будет при сохранении элемента (и его свойств - иногда требуется отдельный обработчик, если свойства сохраняются отдельно) автоматически определять диапазон числа и сохранять его в специально созданное свойство (типа список), в настройках которого уже изначально прописаны все диапазоны. И уже по этому свойству фильтровать в умном фильтре.

Возможно, обработчик - не лучшая идея. В некоторых случаях лучше написать скрипт, который регулярно будет обходить товары и сохранять нужное значение. Кстати, в Маркетплейсе есть модуль Антирутин - он может помочь в решении этой задачи.